# Hibernate: select elements of given type from association

Tags: hibernate

After updating from Hibernate 5.6.15 to Hibernate 6.4.4, we have an issue with one of our HQL queries.

We have entities of type `Container` that contain a set of type `AbstractEntity`. We also have a subclass of `AbstractEntity`, which is `ConcreteEntity`.

With Hibernate 5 the following query would give us the ids of the elements in the container's set of entities of type `ConcreteEntity`: `select c.id from ConcreteEntity c, Container cn where c in elements(cn.entities) and cn = :CONTAINER`

With Hibernate 6 we get an error that says `user lacks privilege or object not found: C1_1.ENTITY_ID`. If we change the query to `select c.id from AbstractEntity c...`, no error is thrown. However, we only want to select entities of this specific type. Is this still possible with Hibernate 6?

The relevant parts of our mappings look like this:

```
<class name="Container" table="container">
  <id name="id" column="container_id" type="long"><generator class="native"/></id>
  <set name="entities" table="container_entities" lazy="true">
    <key column="container_id"/>
    <many-to-many column="entity_id" class="AbstractEntity" lazy="false"/>
  </set>
</joined-subclass>

<joined-subclass name="ConcreteEntity" extends="AbstractEntity"  table="concrete">
  <key column="concrete_id"/>
</joined-subclass>

<class name="AbstractEntity" table="entity" abstract="true">
  <id name="id" column="entity_id" type="long"><generator class="native"/></id>
</class>
```